# How to select top 10 features from a list of features and a list of weight coefficients ( Logistic Regression )?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, logistic-regression, feature-selection

I want to select top 5 features in my Logistic regression model. I have two arrays now, one having all the feature name and another list having co-efficients from model.coef_ where model = LogisticRegression().

```
feature_list = ['ball', 'cat', 'apple',....,] # this has 108 elements
coefficents = lr.coef_  
print(coefficents[0])
```

This prints follows:

```
[ 2.07587361e-04  5.59531750e-04  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
-5.16353886e-02 ......  1.66633057e-02]   #this also has 108 elements
```

When I try to sort the coeff values, I get a different values.

```
sorted_index = np.argsort(coefficents[0])
print(sorted_index)
[ 22  91  42  15  52  31  16  32  86 .... 17 106]   #this has 108 values
```

How do I get the correct top 5 important features from these two arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`argsort` is sorting in ascending order, you want to have it in descending order (highest first)

Here I give you an easy example:

```
import numpy as np

feature_list = ['ball', 'cat', 'apple', 'house', 'tree', 'school', 'child']
coeff = np.array([0.7, 0.3, 0.8, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.9])
# negate the coeff. to sort them in descending order
idx = (-coeff).argsort()
# map index to feature list
desc_feature = [feature_list[i] for i in idx]
# select the top 5 feature
top_feature = desc_feature [:5]
print(top_feature)
```

results in your top features:

```
['child', 'apple', 'ball', 'tree', 'cat']
```